# In-/Decrementing a Bootstrap progress bar with buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am teaching myself how to set up a website with Bootstrap and I am trying to increment and decrement a Progress bar by one Upvote and one Downvote Button. I want to get the current value of the bar, so I thought I would retreive it from the aria-valuenow. I am fairly new at Javascript/jQuery and I can't wrap my head around it.

I got this far:

```js
var currScore = $('#myProgressBar').attr('aria-valuenow');
        $(function() {
            $('#upvote').on('click', function () {
                var newScore = currScore++;
                });
            $('#downvote').on('click', function () {
                var newScore = currScore--;
                });
            $('#myProgressBar').attr('aira-valuenow', newScore).css('width', newScore+'%');
             });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

parseInt the currScore value

```
 var currScore = $('#myProgressBar').attr('aria-valuenow');
  currScore = parseInt(currScore,10);
        $(function() {
            $('#upvote').on('click', function () {
                var newScore = currScore++;
                });
            $('#downvote').on('click', function () {
                var newScore = currScore--;
                });
            $('#myProgressBar').attr('aira-valuenow', newScore).css('width', newScore+'%');
             });
```